# Can't get data from model in PHP Codigniter using angularjs(link not found error)

Tags: php, angularjs, json, codeigniter

I am new in PHP Codigniter framework. I worked in ASP. Net MVC before. 
Now i wanna learn PHP. In APS i worked with Angularjs with Web Api. 
There i can link like : `$http.get("localhost/api/myApi/getAllData()")`
But i am stuck here in PHP. I can't do link with controller!
My Angular file:

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.constant("dataUrl", "http://localhost/MySite/")
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $filter,dataUrl) {
    console.log('ok')




$scope.users = [];

// Getting the list of users through ajax call.
$http({
    url: dataUrl + 'Home/json_get_user',
    method: "POST",
}).success(function (data) {
    console.log(data)
    $scope.users = data;
})
    .error(function () {
        console.log('error')
    });


});
```

My Home Controller method:

```
   function json_get_user() {
    $arr = array(
        array( "name" => "smith", "age" => "20", "city" => "adelade", "country" => "australia"),
        array("name" => "john", "age" => "20", "city" => "parth", "country" => "australia")

);
     echo json_encode($arr);
 }
```

My Config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';
```

My file physicall location :

```
http://localhost/mySite/
```

But when i run it shows:
[image]

Comment: I think your base url should be `http://localhost/mySite/`

Answer (score 0):

You can use url helper by call

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Then you can use `base_url('resource/location')` method to call your javascript or resource. Then, dont forget to configure your .htaccess file and configure your folder and or file permissions. Although i found much people that forget about that configuration.